# How to read file with argparse correctly in python

Tags: python, csv, argparse

I created a script which read csv file data and display after some calculation.when i run script without argparse it given correct data but when i run with argparse it changed sequence of numbers in csv file.

here is my script code:

```
import csv
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Calculate values from a csv file')
parser.add_argument("path", type=str, help='Transactions amounts')
args = parser.parse_args()

def csv_data(path):
    with open(path) as csv_file:
        readCSV = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        for line in readCSV:
            col_from = line['from']
            col_to = line['to']
            col_ammount = line['amount']
            from_amount = int(float(col_ammount.lstrip('$').replace(',', ''))) - int(
                float(col_ammount.lstrip('$').replace(',', '')))
            to_amount = 0 + int(float(col_ammount.lstrip('$').replace(',', '')))
            print(col_from, '$'+str(from_amount), col_to, '$'+str(to_amount))

csv_data(args.path)
```

I want to run this script with command line correctly with this format:

```
script.py csv file path
```

Comment: I really don't see how your use of argparse (or argparse in general) could change the sequence of numbers *inside* a file you're using.  Are you sure you're specifying the correct file / same file as before you added argparse?

Comment: yes all things are working fine without argparse but when i use argparse it changed the sequence of numbers in csv file.

Comment: If you want to debug to be really sure that the file you are reading is the one you expect, just print its contents.